# SQL Query to fetch multiple least values

Tags: mysql, sql

Input

```
+----+----+----+
| in | tn | 20 |
+----+----+----+
| in | ka | 18 |
+----+----+----+
| in | ap | 30 |
+----+----+----+
| us | la | 12 |
+----+----+----+
| us | ca | 20 |
+----+----+----+
| us | ny | 5  |
+----+----+----+
```

Desired Output

```
+----+----+----+
| in | ka | 18 |
+----+----+----+
| us | ny | 5  |
+----+----+----+
```

As in the above output, i  need each country and its state with least value.

```sql
select a.country, a.state, a.value
from table1 a
where a.value in (select min(value) from table1);
```

With the above query, am getting output based on least value of the entire table.

```
+----+----+---+
| us | ny | 5 |
+----+----+---+
```

I need the least value under each country and its respective state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your approach, you need a correlated subquery:

```
select a.country, a.state, a.value
from table1 a
where a.value in (select min(value)
                  from table1 b
                  where a.country = b.country);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try-

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM mytable b 
JOIN (SELECT country,MIN(val) AS val FROM mytable GROUP BY country) AS a ON b.val=a.val AND a.country=b.country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select country,min(value) from table1 group by country
```

Comment: What about name of the corresponding state?

Comment: That's not whats requested

Comment: _I need the least value under each country and its respective state._

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do that, for example:

```
SELECT a.country,
  ( SELECT b.state
    FROM table1 b
    WHERE b.country = a.country AND b.value = MIN(a.value)) state,
  MIN(a.value)
FROM table1 a
GROUP BY a.country
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

You can use ranking function for this query.

```
Select country, state, value from  
(
    Select row_number() over (order by country, value) as row_id ,
    country, state, value
)T
where row_id == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to sub-query or join! it is simple:

```
select country,state,min(value) from table1 group by country;
```

output:

```
+----+----+----+
| in | ka | 18 |
+----+----+----+
| us | ny | 5  |
+----+----+----+
```